# Error: No application encryption key has been specified. But it exist

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel application which is working well, but whenever I view the log file there are hundreds of error

> production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): No application encryption key has been specified.

exist in log file. There is a key in .`env` file and also I tried `php artisan key:generate` command as well but the error still generated in log file without any visible error to users.

This error only appears in the production server's log file, not in my development pc.

Comment: can you show the `APP_KEY=` value of your env?

Comment: APP_KEY=base64:g7Ta+C5qVWSkdni9/OUsoBNA9GgE3ANrtOquE+JfQv0=

Comment: @EsmatullahArifi heads up, you should never share your app key publically this way.

Comment: @GustavoStraube Not a big deal, it was changed many times before sharing. I shared the old one only to demonstrate that I have the correct key. It is not a real key.

Answer (score 10):

```
php artisan key:generate
```

This will generate a random key, you must **restart the server** and you should no longer see the error message.

run the following commands to clear the cache.

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: I have already told that I used this command but no change in the error log. I tried the last two commands as well.

Comment: @EsmatullahArifi please are you sure you have the key in `.env` file? remove `.env.example` file(if exists)

Comment: Yes, I am sure 100%. this only happens in production server. In my own computer there is no error in log

Comment: Would you mind explaining what each of those commands do? I have had the same problem and even though I've been running config:clear, the error would still show. Now I ran also config:cache and I don't wanna jinx it but it looks like that did the trick.

Comment: If Laravel has cached a configuration value, updating the `.env` file won't have an immediate effect. You need to refresh the configuration cache using `php artisan config:cache` or clear the old cache with `php artisan config:clear` for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 3):

I'm face to the same issue I have searched a lot but in a YouTube video comment I have found a solution (I'm not sure this solution is good or not) but worked for me
copy APP_KEY from .env file
and past in app.php file (located in: your_project\config)
Your app.php will look like

```
.
. 
.
‘key’ => env(‘APP_KEY’, ‘base64:insert key here’),
.
. 
.
```

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck with this problem for a whole day and finally found out it was a permissions issue with the .env file. The file uploaded via scp has no read permissions.

```
chmod -744 .env
```

Hope this helps someone else with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

check the "key" variable form your config/app.php file, it should be

```
 'key' => env('APP_KEY'),
```

OR

make like this

```
'key' => "Your key",
```

And Restart your php server.

Comment: I checked and everything is ok in both files (.env and app.php)

Answer (score 1):

try these commands:

```
composer install
php artisan key:generate
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: how about `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: can you post your `config/app.php`?and hide sensitive credentials.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get going by SSH access into the host that I installed the Laravel on, and then inside the public_html folder, I ran the command `php80 artisan key:generate` It generated the key, and then I refreshed the page, and continued with the install

Answer (score 0):

Yes the `php artisan key:generate` will generate the key for you. like this in console

$`php artisan key:generate
Application key [base64:soAqqNW/Kk85OclhmCKXj+u4nZGF142gEZHEY0Y1NXA=] set successfully.`

you need to copy this key and put it into your .env file in `APP_KEY=` parameter.

Comment: still, the error message exists. I already applied this step.

Comment: @EsmatullahArifi please check your permission access for the project files

Answer (score 0):

Add empty `APP_KEY=` inside .env without value if not exist, then delete `config.php` inside `bootstrap/cache` run `php artisan key:generate`

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Reference

https://web-brackets.com/discussion/5/-solved-no-application-encryption-key-has-been-specified-